# Código de Ordenação não retorna valor correto

Tags: .net, vb.net

Tenho um trabalho de aula cuja necessidade é usar um algoritmo de ordenação para ordenar uma lista de números aleatórios.

Meu problema é que estou jogando os itens da lista dos números aleatórios para um array, implementando o método ordenador e colocando os números ordenados em uma segunda lista.

Porém quando estou fazendo isso sempre retorna o numero 0, ou o erro int32[] array. Como devo proceder?

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    Dim min As Integer
    Dim max As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim best_value As Long
    Dim best_j As Integer

    For i = min To max - 1
        best_value = ve(i)
        best_j = i
        For j = i + 1 To max
            If ve(j) < best_value Then
                best_value = ve(j)
                best_j = j
            End If
        Next j
        vl(best_j) = vl(i)
        vl(i) = best_value

    Next i

    Dim h As Integer
    For h = 0 To 1
        Lst.Items.Add(vl(h))

    Next h

End Sub
```

Neste código **`VE`** é o array dos números aleatórios, **`VL`** é o array dos números já ordenados e **`lst`** é a listbox para qual os números ordenados vão.

Comment: **Uma dica valiosa**: use nomes mais descritivos para suas variáveis. Nomes como **`X`**, **`Y`**, **`VE`**, etc. não são nada bons.

Comment: Obrigado , seguirei suas dicas =D

Comment: Talison, o seu código não está inicializando a variável max, portanto o loop (For i = min To max - 1) nunca será executado. Verifica isso e caso o problema persista posta o código modificado para te ajudarmos.

Answer (score 2):

bom o seu for esta com 2 váriaveis não inicializadas... o min e o max...
tem um programa semelhante que fiz meses atraz que pode ser util pra você... nesse caso meu vetor tem 99 numeros pares aleatorios que no caso ja estão lancados no for
obs: o codigo esta em vba, mas a estrutura é bem semalhante ao vb.net

```
Sub ptnaprova2()

      Dim vet(99) As Integer   Dim x, y, n, aux, menor As Integer
         For x = 0 To 99
        n = Int(Rnd() * 1000) + 1
        If n Mod 2 = 0 Then
          vet(x) = n
        Else
          vet(x) = vet(x) + 1
        End If   Next x

        For x = 0 To 99
          For y = (x + 1) To 99
          If vet(x) > vet(y) Then
            aux = vet(x)
            vet(x) = vet(y)
            vet(y) = aux
          End If
        Next y
          Debug.Print aux
        Next x
         End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click


    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim best_value As Long
    Dim best_j As Integer

    For i = 0 To ve.Length - 1
        best_value = ve(i)
        best_j = i
        For j = i + 1 To ve.Length
            If ve(j) < best_value Then
                best_value = ve(j)
                best_j = j
            End If
        Next j
        vl(best_j) = vl(i)
        vl(i) = best_value

    Next i

    Dim h As Integer
    For h = 0 To 1
        Lst.Items.Add(vl(h))

    Next h

End Sub
```

Basicamente seria isto ? , mas agora esta dando erro na seguinte parte

```
  If ve(j) < best_value Then
```

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in Ordenadores22.exe